# Authentication using SAML 2.0

Tags: typescript, authentication, saml-2.0, vscode-extensions

I am looking for examples where I can authenticate my vs code extension using SAML 2.0. I couldn't find any examples or any link that confirms if VS code extension supports SAML 2.0 authentication. Is it possible to perform SAML authentication in VS code extension ?

Comment: VSCode extensions are in general Node.js applications. So anything you learn about Node.js and SAML is applicable.

Comment: https://github.com/node-saml/passport-saml